# How to print the path traversed in this Dijkstra's algo?

Tags: java

I am not able to print the path traversed using Dijkstra's algorithm. I am getting the right shortest path cost but not able to print the path or nodes that are being traversed for the shortest path.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class DijkstraAlgorithmSet
{
private int distances[];
private Set<Integer> settled;
private Set<Integer> unsettled;
private int number_of_nodes;
private int adjacencyMatrix[][];

public DijkstraAlgorithmSet(int number_of_nodes)
   {
    this.number_of_nodes = number_of_nodes;
    distances = new int[number_of_nodes + 1];
    settled = new HashSet<Integer>();
    unsettled = new HashSet<Integer>();
    adjacencyMatrix = new int[number_of_nodes + 1][number_of_nodes + 1];
}

public void dijkstra_algorithm(int adjacency_matrix[][], int source)
{
    int evaluationNode;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_nodes; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= number_of_nodes; j++)
            adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = adjacency_matrix[i][j];

    for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_nodes; i++)
    {
        distances[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    unsettled.add(source);
    distances[source] = 0;      
    while (!unsettled.isEmpty())
    {
        evaluationNode = getNodeWithMinimumDistanceFromUnsettled();
        unsettled.remove(evaluationNode);
        settled.add(evaluationNode);
        evaluateNeighbours(evaluationNode);
    } 
}

private int getNodeWithMinimumDistanceFromUnsettled()
{
    int min ;
    int node = 0;

    Iterator<Integer> iterator = unsettled.iterator();
    node = iterator.next();
    min = distances[node];
    for (int i = 1; i <= distances.length; i++)
    {
        if (unsettled.contains(i))
        {
            if (distances[i] <= min)
            {
                min = distances[i];
                node = i;           
            }
        }
    }
    return node;
}

private void evaluateNeighbours(int evaluationNode)
{
    int edgeDistance = -1;
    int newDistance = -1;

    for (int destinationNode = 1; destinationNode <= number_of_nodes;          destinationNode++)
    {
        if (!settled.contains(destinationNode))
        {
            if (adjacencyMatrix[evaluationNode][destinationNode] !=   Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            {
                edgeDistance = adjacencyMatrix[evaluationNode]  [destinationNode];
                newDistance = distances[evaluationNode] + edgeDistance;
                if (newDistance < distances[destinationNode])
                {
                    distances[destinationNode] = newDistance;
                }
                unsettled.add(destinationNode);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String... arg)
{
    int adjacency_matrix[][];
    int number_of_vertices;
    int source = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of vertices");
        number_of_vertices = scan.nextInt();
        adjacency_matrix = new int[number_of_vertices + 1][number_of_vertices + 1];

        System.out.println("Enter the Weighted Matrix for the graph");
        for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_vertices; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= number_of_vertices; j++)
            {
                adjacency_matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
                if (i == j)
                {
                    adjacency_matrix[i][j] = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                if (adjacency_matrix[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    adjacency_matrix[i][j] =  Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                }
            } 
        } 

        System.out.println("Enter the source ");
        source = scan.nextInt();

        DijkstraAlgorithmSet dijkstrasAlgorithm = new DijkstraAlgorithmSet(number_of_vertices);
        dijkstrasAlgorithm.dijkstra_algorithm(adjacency_matrix, source);

        System.out.println("The Shorted Path to all nodes are ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= dijkstrasAlgorithm.distances.length - 1; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(source + " to " + i + " is "+ dijkstrasAlgorithm.distances[i]);
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatch)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong Input Format");
    }
    scan.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Would you please add some specifics to what your problems are? You've posted quite a bit of code to read through to understand what is going wrong in the first place.

Comment: Suppose if i want to go from node 1 to node 4 , it is giving me the shortest path cost , but i am not able to get the edges that are being added ! I also want to print the path it follows to calculate the shortest path cost

Answer (score 0):

As I understand Djikstra's Algorithm for every node you store the current minimum distance needed to get to that node. What you will want to do is to store the path that corresponds to that distance as well. This is slightly tricky considering you are using an adjacency matrix. What you could do is have a second matrix of the same size with the paths stored, I'll call it call it `pathMatrix`. So if we know that it takes `5` distance units to get from `A` (`i=0`, `j=0`) to `C` (`i=2`, `j=2`) you would have `adjacencyMatrix[2][2] = 5` and `pathMatrix[2][2] = [A, B, C]`. `pathMatrix` will be updated at the exact same times that `adjacencyMatrix` is updated. You will just add the next node to the previous node's current path and set it to the next node's entry in `pathMatrix`.